# How to convert Oracle Blob with tiff file format to Blob with jpeg file Format

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

please I need help to Convert Oracle Blob with tiff file format to Blob with jpg or png file Format
Oracle 19c

I tried oracle PLSQL function but the error below rise up

```
FUNCTION convert_JPG (IMAGE in BLOB)
    return blob
 as
   l_JPG_IMAGE  BLOB ;
 BEGIN

   ORDSYS.ORD_IMAGE.processCopy(IMAGE,'fileFormat=JFIF',l_JPG_IMAGE);
   return  l_JPG_IMAGE;
 End ;
```

This is the error stack

```
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception ORA-06512: at 
"ORDSYS.ORDIMAGE", line 456 ORA-06512: at "ORDSYS.ORD_IMAGE", line 330 ORA- 
06512: at "CONVERT_JPG", line 7
```

Answer (score 2):

ORDSYS.ORD_IMAGE is part of **Oracle Multimedia**, which was **removed in Oracle 19c**. Therefore there is no straightforward solution in PL/SQL. If you know Java the answer above is probably the easiest solution.

Source:
[Convert blob image to PUBLIC.ORDIMAGE in plsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494349/convert-blob-image-to-public-ordimage-in-plsql)

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a Java program to [convert TIFF to another format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17561576/1509264).
2. Use a [`CREATE JAVA` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5013.htm#SQLRF01211) to load that program into the database.
3. Create a PL/SQL function to wrap the Java function.
4. Call that function from PL/SQL.

A similar example which shows how to read a `BLOB`, process it (in this case unzip it rather than image processing) and then return the output as a `BLOB` is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59250531/1509264).